# Cookie corruption with multiple createHTTPClient Titanium calls

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cookies, titanium, appcelerator

While creating an Android app in Appcelerator's Titanium that involves both webView and background calls, I ran into a problem / bug where the cookies were getting corrupted on multiple createHTTPClient calls.

Cookies were originally obtained from the webView:

```
var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView();
webview.url = 'http://www.example.com';
window.add(webview);
webview.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    cookies = e.source.evalJS("document.cookie");
    Titanium.App.Properties.setString('cookies',cookies);
}
window.open({modal:true});
```

and then later used with a background call:

```
var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();  
loader.open("GET",base_url + url); 
loader.onload = function() {
    // process response
}
loader.setRequestHeader('Cookie',Titanium.App.Properties.getString("cookies"));
loader.send();
```

The first time the above createHTTPClient chunk of code was called, everything worked, but subsequent runs of the above code would send corrupted cookies. In Google App Engine (gae), printing out the request headers would look like this (broken):

```
logging.info('Request:\n%s' % self.request)
```

broken response (only the cookie portion of the request header is shown)

`Cookie: auth="eyJfdXNlciI6WzYsMSwiVmRoZEtnYWZRMnNxazFjaVM0U1lKdCIsMTM1NzIyMzcwOSwxMzU3MjIzNzA5XX0\075|1357223709|4f622167f477a8c82cab196af4b0029af1a966d7", auth=eyJfdXNlciI6WzYsMSwiVmRoZEtnYWZRMnNxazFjaVM0U1lKdCIsMTM1NzIyMzcwOSwxMzU3MjIzNzA5XX0\075|1357225569|7a469fab7a38a437649c25620729e07c4607f617
Cookie2: $Version=1`

working response

`Cookie:       auth="eyJfdXNlciI6WzYsMSwiVmRoZEtnYWZRMnNxazFjaVM0U1lKdCIsMTM1NzIyMzcwOSwxMzU3MjIzNzA5XX0\075|1357223709|4f622167f477a8c82cab196af4b0029af1a966d7"`
    ...

I suspect the issue has something to do with unicode characters or something inside `createHTTPClient`. Two `auth=` statements are shown in the corrupted cookie.

In summary, when the app first launches, the background `Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient` call works, and any calls after that appear to send corrupted cookies.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTPClient documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) says "object is intended to be used for a single request," so I assumed everything would reset after multiple calls. But something was different after the first call.

Adding `loader.clearCookies(base_url);` to the code before setting the cookies seems to fix the issue.

```
var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();  
loader.open("GET",base_url + url); 
loader.onload = function() {
    // process response
}
loader.clearCookies(base_url); // THE FIX.
loader.setRequestHeader('Cookie',Titanium.App.Properties.getString("cookies"));
loader.send();
```