# Android - Connect to URL with sending cookie

Tags: android

I have to connect to multiple urls, it is some sort of "like" button and there are multiple articles that you can "like".

I first have to login, when logged it I receive a cookie and I have to send the cookie when connecting to the url.

This is the cookie I get:

[[version: 0][name: _website_session][value: 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--857b2e9d3823a16d31761b1677e6d00603ee25ba][domain: .website.nu][path: /][expiry: Sun Jun 02 13:04:16 CEST 2013]]

How can I connect to a url with sending cookies?

****Edit****

I use this method:

```
      second_client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
      String getURL = "http://website.nu/look/hype" + hype_id;
      HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
      HttpResponse responseGet = second_client.execute(get, localContext);
```

localContext is my cookie string

This works, but no other method works for me.
The reason why I'm looking for another method is because this method only works once.. When I try this multiple times after eachother it only works the first time..

Can anyone help me?

Comment: why is it a bother that it works only once ? can you create the cookie several times, then execute() with this new cookie ?

Comment: Image a button as the facebook "like" button. You can "like" multiple items. Everytime you click the "like" button it connects to the URL with sending cookies. This is why it needs to be executed multiple times @antitrust

Comment: ok but then create a httpclient, httpresponse each time. isnt is doable ?

Comment: I'm doing already that. Each time the button is clicked it makes a new httpclient and httpresponse. But only the first time works, after that it doesn't get "liked" @antitrust

Comment: edited my post, dontknow if it helps

Comment: is it improving with clear cookies ?

Comment: I can't work today, I'll try it out tomorrow. I'll report the result @antitrust

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HttpContext` to which you bind your cookie, then `execute()` an `HttpClient` passing this context in arguments. Something in this flavour

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
Cookie cookie = BasicClientCookie("name", "value");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("myUrl"); 

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
```

More elaboration [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133993/sending-cookie-info-in-httprequest).

**EDIT**

An idea [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141746/cookie-corruption-with-multiple-createhttpclient-titanium-calls): before you send the response with execute(), you clearCookie for your url one way or another. With titanium, syntax would be

```
var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();  
loader.open("GET",base_url + url); 
loader.onload = function() {
    // process response
}
loader.clearCookies(base_url); // THE FIX.
loader.setRequestHeader('Cookie',Titanium.App.Properties.getString("cookies"));
loader.send();
```

cannot find the command for android but you got the idea.